# Get Permalink of included custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a site that uses normal posts for news - and a custom post type for projects.

To be able to show the content of the projects in the news section too, I've added a custom option (with ACF) to include the data from a project in a news article. Together with a custom template this has allowed me to let a normal news post look exactly the same as a project. This allows me to show both news and projects chronologically on the home page.

This has one drawback: duplicate content.

To combat this I've added the canonical element in my header.

Where I'm stuck however is that I don't seem to find a way to get the permalink of the included project as the canonical link - as it will of course take the link of the news post.

I am able to get the permalink of the project in the news article - within the loop. Now I need to find a way to get it in the header too - dynamically.

Can this be done with a callback function / action? If so could you provide an example?